# My Flutter Mobile Browser app can't handle/load external link from other apps in own WebView new tabs

Tags: flutter, browser, webview, android-webview, flutter-inappwebview

I'm working on a mobile browser app using flutter_inappwebview package.
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview
https://inappwebview.dev/docs/intro

It has **home_page.dart** with OpenNewTab() to open a New Tab opening the search query.
**webview_tab.dart**: where InAppWebView & it's initialSettings are defined.
**webview_modal.dart**: a modal class for creating New Tabs in browser.

I wanted to load external links from other apps on system in New Tab in my Browser so
created **openExternalLink()** to load external links in new tabs.
Intent filters in Android Manifest are added.

**Current** **Behaviour**: After app is installed, only first external link from any app clicked > Choose Browser > My_Flutter_Browser app choosen.  Only that first link loads in my flutter browser instance running in that messaging app/WhatsApp instead of opening a separate tab in my flutter browser. That first link loaded is visible in WhatsApp which has my flutter browser opened inside it.  But that link tab is not opened/ that link tab not visible separately in my browser. After first link, subsequent click on external links and choosing my browser opens my browser app but doesn't load link in new tab.

**Expected Behaviour**: On clicking link in WhatsApp> Choose Browser> my_flutter_browser > Opens Link In New Tab. On Subsequent clicks on same or other external links, open those new tabs respectively.

webview_tab.dart

```
class _WebViewTabState extends State<WebViewTab> with WidgetsBindingObserver {

  // List<NavigationRequest> externalNavigationRequests = [];

  List<String> externalLinks = [];

  bool isInitialLoad = true;

  // void openExternalLink(String url) {

  //   externalLinks.add(url);

  //   _webViewController?.loadUrl(urlRequest: URLRequest(url: widget.webViewModel.url));

  // }

  void openExternalLink(String url) {

    var browserModel = Provider.of<BrowserModel>(context, listen: false);

    var settings = browserModel.getSettings();

    externalLinks.add(url);

    _webViewController?.loadUrl(urlRequest: URLRequest(url: widget.webViewModel.url));

    browserModel.addTab(WebViewTab(

      key: GlobalKey(),

      webViewModel: WebViewModel(

          url: widget.webViewModel.url),

    ));

  }

  // void openNewTab(value) {

  //   var browserModel = Provider.of<BrowserModel>(context, listen: false);

  //   var settings = browserModel.getSettings();

  //

  //   browserModel.addTab(WebViewTab(

  //     key: GlobalKey(),

  //     webViewModel: WebViewModel(

  //         url: WebUri(value.startsWith("http")

  //             ? value

  //             : settings.searchEngine.searchUrl + value)),

  //   ));

  // }

  void goBack() {

    if (externalLinks.isNotEmpty) {

      externalLinks.removeLast();

      if (externalLinks.isNotEmpty) {

        String previousUrl = externalLinks.last;

        _webViewController?.loadUrl(urlRequest: URLRequest(url: widget.webViewModel.url));

      }

    }

  }

  InAppWebViewController? _webViewController;

  PullToRefreshController? _pullToRefreshController;

  FindInteractionController? _findInteractionController;

  bool _isWindowClosed = false;

  final TextEditingController _httpAuthUsernameController =

      TextEditingController();

  final TextEditingController _httpAuthPasswordController =

      TextEditingController();

  @override

  void initState() {

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);

    super.initState();

    _pullToRefreshController = kIsWeb

        ? null

        : PullToRefreshController(

            settings: PullToRefreshSettings(

              color: Colors.blue

            ),

            onRefresh: () async {

              if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {

                _webViewController?.reload();

              } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {

                _webViewController?.loadUrl(

                    urlRequest:

                        URLRequest(url: await _webViewController?.getUrl()));

              }

            },

          );

    _findInteractionController = FindInteractionController();

  }

...


@override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(

      color: Colors.white,

      child: _buildWebView(),

    );

 
 }

InAppWebView _buildWebView() {

    final themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context);

    var browserModel = Provider.of<BrowserModel>(context, listen: true);

    var settings = browserModel.getSettings();

    var currentWebViewModel = Provider.of<WebViewModel>(context, listen: true);

    if (Util.isAndroid()) {

      InAppWebViewController.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(

          settings.debuggingEnabled);

    }

    var initialSettings = widget.webViewModel.settings!;

    //DATA HANDLING

    //1) DATABASE API

    initialSettings.databaseEnabled = true;

    //2) LOCAL STORAGE API

    initialSettings.domStorageEnabled = true;

    initialSettings.allowContentAccess = false;

    //3) FILE SYSTEM API

    initialSettings.allowFileAccess = true;

    //4) CACHE API

    // initialSettings.cacheMode = CacheMode.LOAD_DEFAULT;

    //WEBVIEW UI & LAYOUT HANDLING

    initialSettings.loadWithOverviewMode = true;

    initialSettings.supportMultipleWindows = true;

    initialSettings.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true;

    initialSettings.dataDetectorTypes = [DataDetectorTypes.ALL];

    initialSettings.useOnDownloadStart = true;

    initialSettings.useOnLoadResource = true;

    initialSettings.useShouldOverrideUrlLoading = true;

    initialSettings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;

    initialSettings.userAgent =

        "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; LG-H870 Build/PKQ1.190522.001) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Mobile Safari/537.36";

    initialSettings.transparentBackground = true;

    initialSettings.safeBrowsingEnabled = true;

    initialSettings.disableDefaultErrorPage = true;

    initialSettings.supportMultipleWindows = true;

    initialSettings.verticalScrollbarThumbColor =

        const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

    initialSettings.horizontalScrollbarThumbColor =

        const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

    initialSettings.allowsLinkPreview = false;

    initialSettings.isFraudulentWebsiteWarningEnabled = true;

    initialSettings.disableLongPressContextMenuOnLinks = true;

    initialSettings.allowingReadAccessTo = WebUri('file://$WEB_ARCHIVE_DIR/');

    return InAppWebView(

      initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: widget.webViewModel.url),

      initialSettings: InAppWebViewSettings(

        forceDark: themeProvider.isDarkMode ? ForceDark.ON : ForceDark.OFF,

        allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,

        preferredContentMode: UserPreferredContentMode.DESKTOP,

      ),

      windowId: widget.webViewModel.windowId,

      pullToRefreshController: _pullToRefreshController,

      findInteractionController: _findInteractionController,

      onWebViewCreated: (controller) async {

        initialSettings.transparentBackground = false;

        await controller.setSettings(settings: initialSettings);

        _webViewController = controller;

        widget.webViewModel.webViewController = controller;

        widget.webViewModel.pullToRefreshController = _pullToRefreshController;

        widget.webViewModel.findInteractionController = _findInteractionController;

        if (Util.isAndroid()) {

          controller.startSafeBrowsing();

        }

        widget.webViewModel.settings = await controller.getSettings();

        if (isCurrentTab(currentWebViewModel)) {

          currentWebViewModel.updateWithValue(widget.webViewModel);

        }

      },

      shouldOverrideUrlLoading: (controller, navigationAction) async {

        var url = navigationAction.request.url;

        if (url != null && url.host != Uri.parse(widget.webViewModel.url as String).host) {

          openExternalLink(url.toString());

          return NavigationActionPolicy.CANCEL;

        }

        return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;

      },

      onLoadStart: (controller, url) async {

        widget.webViewModel.isSecure = Util.urlIsSecure(url!);

        widget.webViewModel.url = url;

        widget.webViewModel.loaded = false;

        widget.webViewModel.setLoadedResources([]);

        widget.webViewModel.setJavaScriptConsoleResults([]);

        if (isCurrentTab(currentWebViewModel)) {

          currentWebViewModel.updateWithValue(widget.webViewModel);

        } else if (widget.webViewModel.needsToCompleteInitialLoad) {

          controller.stopLoading();

        }

        if (isInitialLoad) {

          isInitialLoad = false;

        } else {

          openExternalLink(url.toString());

        }

      },
```

**Android Manifest**

```
<intent-filter Android:autoVerify="true">

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="http" />

                <data android:scheme="https" />

                <!-- Add more schemes if your app supports additional protocols -->

            </intent-filte
r>
```

Info.plist

```
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>myflutterbrowser</string> <!-- Replace with your app scheme -->
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `webview_modal.dart` file in the code you shared doesn't seem to manage multiple tabs or keep track of them.you'll need to modify your implementation to include tab management and handle the creation of new tabs.

Create a `Tab class` to represent each `tab` in your browser. The class can have properties like `url` and `webView` to store the URL and corresponding `InAppWebViewController` for each tab.

Modify the `WebViewTab` widget to include a reference to the Tab it belongs to. You can pass the `Tab instance` as a parameter to the `WebViewTab widget.`

In the `openExternalLink() function,` create a `new Tab` instance with the given URL and add it to your tab management logic.

Implement a mechanism to switch between tabs and display the corresponding web content. This can be done by updating the `WebViewTab widget` with the current URL from its associated Tab when the tab is selected.